# How can I implement time based time series windowing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, time-series

I want to window a pandas series which has a `DatetimeIndex` to the last X seconds. Usually I'd use [pandas.Series.rolling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rolling.html#pandas-series-rolling) for windowing. However the datetime indices are not equidistant means I cannot calculate the number of data points in a reliable manner. How can I implement a time based windowing (e.g. by implementing a [`BaseIndexer`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.api.indexers.BaseIndexer.html) subclass and passing it to the `window` parameter of `rolling()`)?

Comment: Doesn't something like `df.rolling('2s')` work? "2s" here indicates last 2 seconds

Comment: No, it does not. If you look at the API `window` has to be an int or an instance of BaseIndexer subclass.

Comment: The builtin BaseIndex subclasses https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/window/indexers.py are not helpful as well.

Comment: The docs (the link you shared) have an example with a `df.rolling('2s')` at the end - I haven't tried it out though

Comment: The example applies to dataframes and I totally ignored it. However seems to work for Series as well. I get a `Rolling` object instance but I need to convert it back to a pd.Series somehow.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get the last X seconds from a datetime indexed series I came up with is getting the `newest_timestamp = series.index.max()`, calculating the oldest timestamp to consider from it `oldest_timestamp = newest_timestamp - pd.to_timedelta(<X-seconds>, unit='s')` and slicing the `windowed_series = series[oldest_timestamp:newest_timestamp`. Cause the `oldest_timestamp` is not extracted from the series but calculated the slicing operation will usually not match exactly. However this does not matter cause it is handled automatically.

NOTE: `series.rolling()` is usually used in a time series data pre-processing context (e.g. weighting samples within a window dependent on a function as part of a forecasting application) not for plain windowing use cases.